# What do the eigenvectors of the Hessian matrix actually represent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

It is known in multivariate calculus that, at a critical point $p_c = (x_{1c}, x_{2c}, ... , x_{nc})$ of the function $f(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$, if the Hessian is positive definite we have a local minimum and if it is negative definite we have a local maximum.  However, I'm curious about the eigen*vectors* of the Hessian.  Do they represent anything useful?  For instance, do they represent an ellipsoid inside of which $f(p_c)$ is the global maximum/minimum?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Sorry about that.  That question answers it handily.

Comment: @amd: please see the above comment thread